# Send a mail that displays a video in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to display a video inside of a mail (coded in an `html.erb` file). I have tried this with an `iframe` tag, but it doesn't work (the same code works in a normal html page, so I'm sure that the mistake doesn't come from here). Is it possible to do it without any gem ? Which tag should I use then ?
The website is coded in **rails 4.2**. The source of the video is a **youtube link**.

Thank you very much for your help !

PS: I have searched for an answer, yet, if I missed a related topic, I'll be glad for you to give me the link.

Comment: The problem is more in html and email than in Rails. Try to create such email and attach it here.

Comment: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/309

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, @BradWerth ! :)

Comment: I don't think email clients support iframes or playing videos. They are really really restrictive about what you can display.